# gpg decrypting multiple files in one stream

Tags: linux, command-line, security, encryption

I would like to decrypt several gpg encrypted files in one single stream to be piped to another command without any temporary file.
$ cat foo1.txt.gpg foo2.txt.gpg | gpg -d | wc -l
will count only the lines of foo1, not including foo2.

The --decrypt-files option is able to decrypt multiple files but doesn't seem to be able to pipe all decrypted files on a single stdout:
$ gpg --decrypt-files foo*.txt.gpg | wc -l (will output 0 )

Any hint is welcome

Answer (score 3):

I guess you should use multiple gpg invocations in a loop:

```
{ for i in foo1.txt.gpg foo2.txt.gpg; do gpg -d < $i; done; } | wc -l
```

The multiple gpg invocations will ask for your password multiple times unless you use gpg agent or similar:

```
gpg-agent --daemon sh -c \
'{ for i in foo1.txt.gpg foo2.txt.gpg; do gpg -d < $i; done; } | wc -l'
```

Comment: @revher: Glad to head that. Feel free to accept this answer to indicate this fact. You can still change your check mark later on if some better answer should come up.